# power-failure during update and now a black screen, won't boot

Tags: boot, upgrade

My computer shut down during an update because of a power outage. After rebooting the computer, nothing but a blank, black screen is displaying with a fixed mouse in the centre of the screen. Can this be fixed or do I need to re-install?

Comment: Boot a live usb and identify your graphics card. Also check to make sure you do not have a hardware problem. Update your question to include your video card and version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described, it appears as if the power outage you experienced happened during an update to some of the system software. The outage essentially "bricked" your computer -- made its operating system completely unusable. You will need to reinstall the operating system.

Small suggestion - if at all possible, try to backup or copy any of your valuable files to an external location (e.g. a USB pen drive), you might not want to lose them when you reinstall.